# Why does sinon fakeserver not reply to request from Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sinon

I am chasing a race condition since days now. I am really glad for any help. This is both a sinon fakeserver and a Vue.js related question.

Here is the setup of [my little project](https://github.com/Doogiemuc/liquido-vue-frontend):

- The project is based on the awesome [vue webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).
- I have a rather elaborate vue component called [DoogieTable](https://github.com/Doogiemuc/liquido-vue-frontend/blob/master/src/components/DoogieTable.vue) that shows a table. It can load data from a remote REST endpoint. (using vue-resource)
- I have a [mocha test case for DoogieTable](https://github.com/Doogiemuc/liquido-vue-frontend/blob/master/test/unit/specs/DoogieTable.spec.js). The second test about loading remote data into the table is my problem.
- The test mocks the xHhtmlRequest with sinon.fakeServer and responds with canned data.

This works as long as I set `fakeServer.autoRespond = true;` But according to the sinon doc, this is not suitable for production ready unit tests.

**When/Where in the code of my test case do I have to call `fakeServer.respond()` ?**

---

Things I already tried:

- Calling it right after the the vue component DoogieTable became ready => that seems to be to early. At that point in time, the request to load data has not been send by the component. (I think. I am not quite sure)
- Calling in a vm.$nextTick callback => same problem. No request yet.